# Importing RestAssured in Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured

I have developed a Spring Boot Application.
I am using RestAssured to test the same

following are the dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile('com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.4.1')
}
```

I am facing a problem while importing RestAssured in a Integration Test class for Spring Boot

```
 import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
```

When I try to run the application using gradle I am getting the following error

> Error:(15, 37) java: package com.jayway.restassured does not exist

Why is this problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure that all the dependencies have downloaded? May this happen in your IDE, make sure running gradle build from the command line.

Comment: If you are using intellij, make sure you hit the **'Refresh all Gradle projects'** button, if you are adding Gradle dependencies